# Java Bean Validation - Intercepting Validations

Tags: spring-boot, validation, javabeans

I have the following scenario: I am trying to process a form and the model attribute is a bean with String and Long properties. As you all guys know, bean validation offers a lot of annotation to help us determine the validity of the data.
What I am facing is that, for the case of the Long attributes, I can only use @NotNull and another annotation (I dont recall its name) to force the user to enter positive numbers. If the user enters for instance "sdf", the application throws a BIG exception. So what I would like to know is If I can intercept the form processing and validate by my own if the user entered a numeric thing before it explodes (because I cant use @Pattern)... and I cant switch that attribute to String...

Was it clear ?.

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring Custom validation. That is Annotation-based validation and you have the ability to create your own custom validation logic. [Spring Custom Validation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator) In this link you can find out more examples and how to use it.

Comment: Thankx bro... Will check if the link helps...

Comment: Thankx for your time... I remembered using this approach for another scenario but, for this case, NotNull and Positive doesnt help me to show to the user if he entered words... For the case of a long attribute... If it were a String, it would be easier as I would use @Pattern (which breaks for a Long attr)